# Change Windows 10 text size (DPI) programatically without restart

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-10, dpi

I need a program that would drag the value of the text size slider in Win 10 settings to 100% (or some other parametrized value).

[image: Settings]

There are some methods described i.e. here: [Change windows dpi setting C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23886034/2224701). But restart is needed to apply a registry change. I am looking for a script that changes Win 10 DPI without restart.

I expect to accomplish this in C# or PowerShell preferably without any big linked external libraries. Is that possible?

Comment: May I ask why would you need that? May be we could think of other ways as well..

Comment: @Sak Some remote viewer programs do not work well with DPI higher than 100%.

Comment: Answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233182/how-can-i-change-windows-10-display-scaling-programmatically-using-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change Windows 10 Display Scaling Programmatically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233182/how-can-i-change-windows-10-display-scaling-programmatically-using-c-sharp)

Comment: The main problem is that the solution posted in that linked question does not work. I will eventually edit or delete this question but I am  still unsure how Creators update affects the problem.

Answer (score -1):

(Edited due to a typing error)
PowerShell.  Make sure to set the execution policy.

```
#Load ntuser.dat
reg load HKU\UserProfile C:\users\UserProfile \NTUSER.DAT

# Create a new key, close the handle, and trigger collection
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKU\UserProfile\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name 'DPIScalingVer' -Value 60

#Unload ntuser.dat
reg unload HKU\UserProfile
```

Comment: Returns `Set-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKU\UserProfile \Control Panel\Desktop' because it does not exist.` There are possibly extra spaces in the string. Perhaps also some explanation why this should work would be handy.

Comment: Even after executing `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File .\install\test.ps1` and deleting extra spaces it says `Set-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKU\UserProfile\Control Panel\Desktop' because it does not exist`

Comment: Have you tried going into regedit and verifying you have the registry key?  I have the Key in my version on Win10.  Also, I noticed a typing error in my PowerShell.  I accidentally added a space after UserProfile.  Did you delete that space?